# Two HeaderValueRouters in same configuration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In my project I use Spring Integration. I have following configuration.

I use HeaderValueRouter in first place like this : (it is in some chain)

```
<int:header-value-router id="router1" header-name="SOME_HEADER"
                         default-output-channel="channelA">
<int:mapping value="a" channel="channelA" />
<int:mapping value="b" channel="channelB" />
<int:mapping value="c" channel="channelC" />
...
```

Now let's say that the Spring Integration route my message to channel ***channelA***

In this channel I enrich again headers because of information I get from routing. Which looks like that : (it is in some chain too)

```
<int:header-value-router id="router2" header-name="SOME_HEADER_2"
                         default-output-channel="channelD">
<int:mapping value="d" channel="channelD" />
<int:mapping value="e" channel="channelE" />
<int:mapping value="f" channel="channelF" />
...
```

But what happens is that it does not route during the second HeaderValueRouter properly. It searches for bean called 'd' instead of looking for channel 'channelD'.

> DestinationResolutionException: failed to look up MessageChannel with name 'd' in the BeanFactory

I have debugged it and found out that in Parent class of HeaderValueRouter which is AbstractMappingMessageRouter, on its map, which contains mapping for channels, there are only channels from first mapping : "channelA", "channelB", "channelC".

What is odd, both of this headerValueRouters have same values on this map, even tho these two are different objects with differents mappings.

They have different IDs and different headers, and yet they use same map within parent class.

Does SI build both HeaderValueRouter's with same mappings at the beginning or what?

How does it work?

EDIT :

Here is more of configuration, with as much information as I can safely give :

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
         (some JMS config)
/>

<int:channel id="splitterTask" />

<int:chain id="splitterChain" input-channel="splitterTask">

    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="MODULE" value="splitter" overwrite="true"/>
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:service-activator ref="someService" method="putMdc"/>

    <int:service-activator ref="someService2" method="persist" />

    <int:header-value-router
            header-name="REQUEST_TYPE"
            default-output-channel="channelA">
        <int:mapping value="a" channel="channelA" />
        <int:mapping value="b" channel="channelB" />
        <int:mapping value="c" channel="channelC" />
        <int:mapping value="special" channel="channelSpecial" />
    </int:header-value-router>

</int:chain>

<int:channel id="channelA" />

...

<int:channel id="channelB" />

...

<int:channel id="channelC" />

...

<!-- again, headers -->
<int:channel id="channelSpecial" />

<int-xml:xpath-expression (some xpath config)/>


<int:chain id="someChain" input-channel="channelSpecial">

    <int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>
        <int-xml:header name="TEMPLATE" xpath-expression-ref="exp"/>
    </int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>

    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="REQUEST_TYPE" ref="some_bean" method="getRequestType" overwrite="true" />
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:header-value-router
            header-name="REQUEST_TYPE"
            default-output-channel="channelD" >
        <int:mapping value="d" channel="channelD" />
        <int:mapping value="e" channel="channelE" />
        <int:mapping value="f" channel="channelF" />
    </int:header-value-router>

</int:chain>
```

EDIT2 :

I checked it in new project with SpringBoot and SI, and yeah it works, but i forget to say that it is deployed on the WildFly 10. I think that it is nearly impossible to reconstruct the exact enviroment of this big context outside of it. I will try. If I succeed, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Works well for me:

```
<chain input-channel="routingInput">
    <header-value-router id="router1" header-name="SOME_HEADER"
                         default-output-channel="channelA">
        <mapping value="a" channel="channelA"/>
        <mapping value="b" channel="channelB"/>
        <mapping value="c" channel="channelC"/>
    </header-value-router>
</chain>

<chain input-channel="channelA">
    <header-value-router id="router2" header-name="SOME_HEADER_2"
                             default-output-channel="channelD">
        <mapping value="d" channel="channelD" />
        <mapping value="e" channel="channelE" />
        <mapping value="f" channel="channelF" />
    </header-value-router>
</chain>

<channel id="channelD">
    <queue/>
</channel>
```

---

```
@Autowired
private MessageChannel routingInput;

@Autowired
private PollableChannel channelD;

@Test
public void testHeaderValueRouter() {
    this.routingInput.send(
            MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo")
                    .setHeader("SOME_HEADER", "a")
                    .setHeader("SOME_HEADER_2", "d")
                    .build());

    assertNotNull(this.channelD.receive(10_000));
}
```

Would be great if you are able to share similar fully useful configuration for testing from our side.